# Outputting integers from user input external files (arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, null

So I am currently having trouble in outputting the integers for each of the index and its element

My instructions was to match the outputs these two text files:

electricity.txt

```
number of integers in file "electricity.txt" = 4
    index = 0, element = 1877
    index = 1, element = 1923
    index = 2, element = 1879
    index = 3, element = 2000
```

1000.txt  from index 0 to 1000

```
number of integers in file "1000.txt" = 1001
    index = 0, element = 1000
    index = 1, element = 2
    index = 2, element = 3
    index = 3, element = 5
    index = 4, element = 7
    index = 5, element = 11
    index = 6, element = 13
    .....
    ...
    index = 1000, element = 7919
```

Here is my code:

```css
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
 
public class PaulGeorge03
{
     /*************************************************************
     *  Outputs integers from user input external files.
     ********************************************************************************/
    
   public static void main(String[] commandlineArguments)throws InputMismatchException 
   {
      if(commandlineArguments.length == 0)
      {
         System.out.println("Please enter the file name " +
               "as the 1st commandline argument.");
      }
      else{
                       
         
         Integer[] array = PaulGeorge03.readFileReturnIntegers(commandlineArguments[0]);
         PaulGeorge03.printArrayAndIntegerCount(array, commandlineArguments[0]);
      }
   } 
   public static Integer []readFileReturnIntegers(String inputFile)
   {
        
      Integer [] array = new Integer [10000];
        
      
      File file = new File(inputFile);
            
      Scanner scanFile = null;
            
      try {
         scanFile = new Scanner(file);
      } 
      catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
                  
         System.out.print("ERROR: File not found for \"");
         System.out.println(inputFile +"\"");
      }  
                   
      if(scanFile != null)
      {
         int i=0; // counter 
         while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) 
         {   
            try
            {                       
               int element = scanFile.nextInt(); 
               array[i++]=element;
                                          
            }
            catch (InputMismatchException exception)
            {
               scanFile.next();
            } 
         }
      }         
      return array;          
   }
      
   public static void printArrayAndIntegerCount(Integer [] array, String inputFile)
   { 
      int num = 0;
      Integer lengthOfArray = array.length;
      
      System.out.println("number of integers in file " + inputFile + " = " + lengthOfArray);
      
      for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; i++)
            
         
      {
            
         System.out.println("index = " + i + ", element = "+ array[i]);
         
            
      }
      
      
   }
       
                                                                              
            
}
```

1000.txt works but it would go over the limit which is =4 and go to to 10 
since 
`for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)`

electricity.txt shows up a null after =3 since the required is =10

```
number of integers in file electricity.txt = 10000
index = 0, element = 1877
index = 1, element = 1923
index = 2, element = 1879
index = 3, element = 2000
index = 4, element = null
index = 5, element = null
index = 6, element = null
index = 7, element = null
index = 8, element = null
index = 9, element = null
```

Is there a way for it to not show the null value for both and is there a way to match the size of =4 for electricity.txt and =1001 for 1000.txt if i run the files?

Comment: Use `array.length` in the loop instead of a hardcoded number. And check if the current element in the array is `null` before printing (ps. Lookup "if-statements"), or use the length you get from the file to init an array at the correct lentgh rather than using a huge array.

Comment: you mean changing for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) to for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)? I did that but it started going to 10000 . How would I go bout checking it? sorry arrays are probably my kryptonite in my programming class.

Comment: What do you mean changing?

Comment: Thats because you create an array with a lenght of 10000 at the beginning of your `readFilrReturnInteger()` method. After rereading your instructions, you might wanna dive into a reseizable collection types like the `ArrayList` instead of using a humangeous array. And since this looks a lot like home/schoolwork, I won't give any code example in case you were wondering. So good luck with researching!

Comment: I just don't know what to do next but alright sir.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a for loop use a while loop like

```
while(array[i]!=null) {
    System.out.println(array[i++]);
}
```

This is for printing.

I highly recommend you use ArrayList to store the list. ArrayList has dynamic size which means it will increase on size when you add items to it. Creating a 10000 sized array without the knowledge of how many elements you have is not really a good idea.

Comment: Where is `i` in the while loop incremented? When the first element in the array is not `null`. It will be a veeery long time till that loop is finnished.

Comment: Thanks n247s edited the answer :) I agree with the above comment where someone said he/she thought this was a homework. This is really a basic thing if you are not able to figure it out it means you should do some more studying/researching. Don't take the easy way.